# i2c slave devices with the same address

Tags: embedded, rfid, i2c, stm32, eeprom

I'm developing an embedded system on STM32 F107 that communicates via i2c with 2 slave devices: a rfid reader [rfid manual](http://www.stronglink-rfid.com/en/rfid-modules/sl030.html) and a eeprom module [eeprom manual](http://akizukidenshi.com/download/24fc1025-ip.pdf).
These two devices have the same slave address A0 (for write operations) and A1 (for the read operations).
If a use only one device it works fine. But if I use both of them I have a problem. 
First I read the card id from rfid reader, then I write it in the eeprom (up to here it is all ok), when I try to read again from the rfid reader I get input data that are wrong and always the same even if I change the card.
What is happening and what I can do to solve the problem?

Comment: Can't you modify the address of one of the devices using the jumpers?

Comment: [rfid module](http://www.stronglink-rfid.com/image/modules/SL030.jpg) Are jp1 and jp2 the jumpers that are you talking about?

Comment: Yes, page 6 of the manual.

Comment: While changing the address of one device is the best choice, if for some reason you can't do that, then moving one of the devices to a different set of pins might be an option - either another I2C interface engine if available, or just bit banging on GPIOs if not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Devices must have different addresses. You should reconfigure either device to use a different address to avoid the clash. This is typically done with jumpers (JP1, JP2 on the rfid reader) or by hardwiring some address pins on the chip (A0 and A1 pins on the eeprom chip).

Answer (score 1):

If there is no extra pins available to move the I2C device, try using i2c buffer or i2c MUX.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to alter the address:

1. Change One of the Slave Addresses: If it is viable to configure one of the slave gadgets to have a distinctive I2C slave address, that is the easiest and encouraged solution. Many I2C devices assist you to alternate their deal with via hardware pins or software configuration.
2. Use an I2C Multiplexer (I2C MUX): An I2C multiplexer is a tool that permits you to connect multiple slave gadgets with the identical cope with to the equal I2C bus. It basically acts as a transfer, allowing you to pick which tool to speak with. You can manage the I2C MUX thru the STM32 and pick out the precise slave device for conversation.
3. Implement Software Addressing: If you can not change the addresses of the slave devices and don't need to apply an I2C MUX, you may put into effect software program addressing. This entails temporarily converting the slave deal with of one of the devices even as communicating with it after which restoring the authentic address whilst completed.

Here's a fashionable define of ways you can put into effect software addressing in STM32:

a. Before sending records to the slave tool with the conflicting cope with, send a command to briefly trade its cope with to a completely unique cost.

B. Communicate with the tool the use of the brief deal with.

C. After communique is entire, ship every other command to revert the tool's deal with to the unique price.

Comment: did you use any AI at all in the writing of any part of this answer?